# Cómo cambio la estructura de un archivo CSV generado con PHP?

Tags: php, csv

El siguiente código crea y descarga un archivo `CSV`:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$salida = fopen('saldos.csv', 'w');

if ($salida) {
    # Los encabezados no son necesarios en este caso
    # fputs($salida, "Documento, Obtenido, Acumulado, Nuevo".PHP_EOL);

    $sql = "SELECT documento, obtenido, acumulado, nuevo FROM datos WHERE semana = 6 ";
    $stmt = $dbcon->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            fputs($salida, implode($fila, ';').PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    fclose($salida);
} else {
    echo "Lo sentimos! No se pudo crear el archivo";
}

  ob_end_clean();
  header('Content-Type: application/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=saldos.csv');
  readfile("./saldos.csv");
?>
```

Cuya salida es la siguiente:

```
1040356985;22;92;114
15654895;26;74;100
```

Necesito que la salida del archivo quede de la siguiente manera: _ *para ser cargado posteriormente en un aplicativo diferente*

```
1040356985;6;22
1040356985;7;92
1040356985;8;114
15654895;6;26
15654895;7;74
15654895;8;100
```

Donde `6=obtenido`, `7=acumulado`, `8=nuevo`.

Qúe debo cambiar en el código `PHP` para darle esa estructura al archivo `CSV`?

Comment: No podrás cambiar la estructura de un fichero si lo estás leyendo, yo crearía un nuevo fichero con la estructura que deseas, cierras el otro,guardas el nuevo y que se sobreescriba.

Comment: Cambia tu `fputs($salida, implode($fila, ';').PHP_EOL);` por varios `fputs`con los datos de `$fila`

Comment: @EduBw en ningumo momento el OP ha dicho nada de que este leyendo el fichero. Solo lo esta creando y quiere cambiar su salida por otra.

Comment: puedes hacer un `order by documento`

Comment: No queda muy claro lo de `obtenido, acumulado, nuevo` ... En el resultado que esperas se nota que quieres usar varias veces, para varias líneas, un dato que viene una sola vez en la consulta. En este caso, crea primero tu conjunto de datos, por ejemplo, un array donde metas tres veces valores como `1040356985` y al lado los otros valores correspondientes, luego escribes ese array en el archivo. Podría ponerte un ejemplo, pero no llego a entender tu pregunta ni de donde exactamente sacas cada dato. No se entiende bien de dónde sacas el `6, 7, 8`, esos valores no aparecen en la 1ª salida.

Comment: Por lo visto un simple loop lo resolvería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que por lo que entendi de las otras respuestas esto es lo que estas buscando, agreguen en el loop cada opcion, 6,7,8.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$salida = fopen('saldos.csv', 'w');

if ($salida) {
    # Los encabezados no son necesarios en este caso
    # fputs($salida, "Documento, Obtenido, Acumulado, Nuevo".PHP_EOL);

    $sql = "SELECT documento, obtenido, acumulado, nuevo FROM datos WHERE semana = 6 ";
    $stmt = $dbcon->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            fputs($salida, $fila["documento"] . ';6;' . $fila["obtenido"] . PHP_EOL );
            fputs($salida, $fila["documento"] . ';7;' . $fila["acumulado"] . PHP_EOL );
            fputs($salida, $fila["documento"] . ';8;' . $fila["nuevo"] . PHP_EOL );
        }
    }
    fclose($salida);
} else {
    echo "Lo sentimos! No se pudo crear el archivo";
}

  ob_end_clean();
  header('Content-Type: application/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=saldos.csv');
  readfile("./saldos.csv");
?>
```

Comment: Los datos se generan como lo necesito pero al final me genera una línea vacía. ¿Sabes como la puedo eliminar?

Comment: Tendrias q jugar con la ultima linea y apagar el PHP_EOL que agrego en el final... fputs($salida, $fila["documento"] . ';8;' . $fila["nuevo"] . PHP_EOL ); el PHP_EOL del ultimo bucle crea una nueva linea